# After running 10 or more minutes at my 5K pace my breathing gets VERY wheezy

Tags: running, breathing

After running 10 or more minutes at my 5K pace my breathing gets *very* wheezy and sort of raspy - but I can still keep running. However I ran a school 1K race a very recently, and I had some difficulty breathing at the end of it.

Is there some sort of reason for this? I'm not asthmatic and have mild hayfever, but that shouldn't be causing this occurrence...

**Note**: I forgot; after running more than 500m I cough a lot. **A lot** - the longer the distance the more I cough - for around half an hour after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be quite a few different causes, from internal to environmental. My first thought is EIB (Exercise Induced Bronchospasm), which used to be called exercise induced asthma. It can be mild to serious.

Other than that, a pulmonologist or other expert should probably be consulted, to rule out anything physical.

Comment: Mild to serious in what way?

Comment: Mild - You cough a lot. Serious - You almost can't breath at all. I have it, and when I get serious about run/cycling training I go to the doc and renew my inhaler prescription. My case is rather mild, so it's more of a "just in case" type thing.

Comment: Would that also be why I get out of breath simply doing pull-ups? since I'm not overweight -> 6'2" and 62kg...

Comment: It's possible. Not to be really alarmist like antrim, but it could also be an early sign of cardiac insufficiency, or any host of things from mild to serious. I really would encourage you to have a phsyical and pulmonary workup done.